# remove all backslashes except in the newline

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk

I want to remove all \ except if it is \n

```
some \'Text\'\nA new line
```

should become

```
some 'Text'\nA new line
```

Comment: Couldn't you just remove all and add a newline at the end of the line? Might be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the character following the backslash if it is not `n`, replace:

```
sed -e 's/\\\([^n]\)/\1/g'
```

You did not specify what to do with backslashes at the end of a line. If you want to remove them, too, you have to add

```
-e 's/\\$//'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sed "s/\\'/'/g"

some 'Text'\nA new line
```

Answer (score 2):

This can make the trick:

```
$ echo "some \'Text\'\nA new line" | sed 's/\\\([^n]\)/\1/g'
some 'Text'\nA new line
```

That is, it replaces `\` as well as there is no `n` after it. The `\([^n]\)` catches the character after `\` so that we can print it back. And that's what we do when making the subtitution: print `\1`, that refers to the character after `\`.

To avoid so many slashes, it can be put also as:

```
$ echo "some \'Text\'\nA new line" | sed 's:\\\([^n]\):\1:g'
some 'Text'\nA new line
```

Comment: We are synchronised, @Jaypal :)

Comment: This deletes the character trailing the backslash if it is not an n. Related to my example the apostrophe around "Text" are missing

Comment: Solved, @tmanthey, now I catch the character and print it back

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
echo "some \'Text\'\nA new line" | sed 's,\\[^n],,g'
```

With `perl`

```
echo "some \'Text\'\nA new line" | perl -pe 's,\\(?!n),,g'
```

Comment: In your sed line parentheses are missing: `sed 's,\\\([^n]\),\1,g'`. This is the same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17065825/2468910) (accepted answer).